# live search in php with an error in mysqli_stmt_close

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Good Day everyone i just want to ask. i want to have a live search but this code doesnt work. nothing happens when i input something and also there is an error in mysqli_stmt_close. can someone help me? Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

Here is for my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
/* Get input value on change */
var inputVal = $(this).val();
var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
if(inputVal.length){
$.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
// Display the returned data in browser
resultDropdown.html(data);
});
} else{
resultDropdown.empty();
}
});

// Set search input value on click of result item
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
$(this).parent(".result").empty();
});
});
</script>

<div class="search-box">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Book..." />
<div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the code for my process for the live search.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Abc123456", "dbdfcamlib");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_books WHERE BookTitle LIKE ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

// Set parameters
$param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

// Check number of rows in the result set
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
// Fetch result rows as an associative array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo "<p>" . $row["BookTitle"] . "</p>";
}
} else{
echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

can someone help me please. thank you..

Comment: First of all its not right approach to start a request after each key entered, what you need to do is either load all the basic data on page load and use select2 to filter it or else you can start search request when user is done with the input query and press search button

Comment: what is wrong in my code sir. i just got it from what i search and after it i edit.

Comment: Okay so what your code is doing is that everytime when a user press some key it is starting a get request to your server and it's for sure that the old request isn't finished and the user will press another key so it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: because according to a tutorial this will work

Comment: First of all change that logic add a new button next to search box and move ur code from keyup input even inside that button click event and then check for php errors!

Answer (score 0):

your method is wrong try this method..

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Database");

   /* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
   }

   $val= "Mr.ram";

   /* create a prepared statement */
   if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT value FROM data WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $val);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

   /* bind result variables */
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

   /* fetch value */
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

   printf("%s is in district %s\n", $val, $district);

   /* close statement */
   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
   }

/* close connection */
 mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What value should i put in the variable $val because you equal it to "Mr.ram"